# Gitlab commit messages link to JIRA

Tags: jira, gitlab

I'm trying to link Gitlab commit messages to JIRA, that is, if a user commits such as:

PROJECT-ID: Some commit message

Then through the Gitlab UI, it links these commit messages to JIRA.

The only way I can seem to do this at the moment takes control of issue tracking itself from Gitlab and links the "Issue" user interface button in Gitlab back to JIRA.

I'd like to still manage and raise issues in Gitlab, but just have Gitlab link any formatted commit messages to JIRA.

I'm using the community addtion

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you set GitLab to use JIRA as your issue tracker, you can't make it link formatted commit messages to JIRA automatically.

You can do this only if you set JIRA to be your issue tracker in GitLab. You can find information about doing that here: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira.html

<strike>**UPDATE**: As Peter said, this functionality is only available using GitLab's [Enterprise Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/).</strike>

**UPDATE**: As jalanb stated in the comment below, this functionality is now available in the community edition as well.

Comment: This requires a GitLab Enterprise Edition. The OP says: "I'm using the community addtion"

Comment: As of version 8.3 this has been backported to GitLab CE, and the docs page has moved to http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/project_services/jira.html

Comment: Do you know if this works on gitlab.com or just self-hosted?

Comment: It looks like you can do this on gitlab.com also. I looked up the following link from my gitlab.com repo. https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/integrations/jira You just need to configure JIRA and Gitlab to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [lesstif/gitlab-jira-integration](https://github.com/lesstif/gitlab-jira-integration) open source solution, that I haven't tried yet myself. It is only a few commits, but I myself considered this approach so it must be sound ;-)

I'm a little confused though. You write you want to use Jira and "I'd like to still manage and raise issues in Gitlab, but just have Gitlab link any formatted commit messages to JIRA." I'm not sure you can get the supertight integration you're looking for. Or maybe I misunderstand.